# Minimal Example: Opening a window in electron from react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Say I am building a desktop application with react/redux & electron. So my index.html file in electron looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 ...
  <body>

    <div id="content"></div>

  <script src="public/js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My biggest React container (call it app.js) is loaded into the 'id=content' div. This works fine so far, but now I am wondering how to open a new file dialog window (or any new window for that matter) when the user clicks a button in my react application.

I found some examples [here](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/) & [here](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/106/how-to-choose-read-save-delete-or-create-a-file-with-electron-framework), but both examples only explain how to load the file dialog window from the main electron processes (in renderer or main).

However, I want the user to engage with my React Application and then, once he or she clicks a button, my app should then tell electron to spawn a new window, and this new window should, of course, somehow be part of my react application.

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide a minimal example here, on how these to things work together.

Answer (score 8):

To open a react component in a new window on button click and detect when the window is closed ***because the component will not simply call `componentWillUnmount` when you close the window*** Your app should look like this

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // To keep track of the new window if opened or closed
      isNewWindow: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
    // onClose will be fired when the new window is closed
    // everything inside NewWindowComponent is considered props.children and will be
    // displayed in a new window
    {(this.state.isNewWindow) &&
    <NewWindowComponent
      onClose={() => this.setState({ isNewWindow: false })>
      <h2>This will display in a new window</h2>
    </NewWindowComponent> }

    <button
      onClick={() => this.setState({ isNewWindow: true })}>
      Open in new window</button>
    )
  }
}
```

**NewWindowComponent.js**

```
export default class NewWindowComponent extends Component {
  // Create a container <div> for the window
  private containerEl = document.createElement('div');

  // This will keep a reference of the window
  private externalWindow = null;

  // When the component mounts, Open a new window
  componentDidMount() {
    // The second argument in window.open is optional and can be set to whichever
    // value you want. You will notice the use of this value when we modify the main
    // electron.js file
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', 'NewWindowComponent ');

    // Append the container div and register the event that will get fired when the
    // window is closed
    if (this.externalWindow)
    {
      this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
      this.externalWindow.onunload = () => this.props.onClose();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl);
  }
}
```

**electron-main.js** or however your main electron file is named

```
...
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    ...
    // You need to activate `nativeWindowOpen`
    webPreferences: { nativeWindowOpen: true },
  });
  ...
  mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window',
    (event, url, frameName, disposition, options, additionalFeatures) =>
    {
      // This is the name we chose for our window. You can have multiple names for
      // multiple windows and each have their options
      if (frameName === 'NewWindowComponent ') {
        event.preventDefault();
        Object.assign(options, {
          // This will prevent interactions with the mainWindow
          parent: mainWindow,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          // You can also set `left` and `top` positions
        });
        event.newGuest = new BrowserWindow(options);
    }
  });
  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 6):

The "createPortal" api in react 16 will help you.

First let's say we have a component like this:

```
<SubWindow>
  <h1>bar</h1>
</SubWindow>
```

Then open(or close) a window in its lifecycle methods like this:

```
export class SubWindow extends React.Component {
  nativeWindowObject: null;

  componentWillMount() {
    this.nativeWindowObject = window.open('');
  }
  render() {
    return this.nativeWindowObject ? ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.nativeWindowObject.document.body) : null;
  }
}
```

Notice: You MUST set webPreferences:{nativeWindowOpen: true} in your main window to make sure "window.open" returns a native Window object. Visit https://electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open for more infomation.

Answer (score 3):

On clicking the button handleNewWindow is called. Make the nodeIntegration to true or preload js.

```
const handleNewWindow =()=> {
    const remote=require('electron').remote;
    const BrowserWindow=remote.BrowserWindow;
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      height: 600,
      width: 800,
      frame:false,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
    }
    });
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app.html#/login`);


  }
```

And on the router file

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

By using this code we can open the reactjs file and route to login. The app.html is main file which is loaded in main.dev.js in electron-react-boilerplate code. The hashing is simplest method to open the reactjs file.
   As the loadURL in electron only loads urls and htmls files we can't open js files.