# Creating new windows with React + Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have an Electron project set up with React. I am attempting to follow the exact same code here:

https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202

It works perfectly fine in Google Chrome. However, in Electron, clicking in the new Window button returns an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
```

I'm assuming that Electron and Chromium handles the new window in a different way than Chrome - I attempted to search for a solution but couldn't find one specific for Chromium or Electron. I've ran through the debugger within Electron. It appears that in `this.externalWindow`, `document` is an undefined property. This problem doesn't show up in Chrome

Any help on what I could be missing?

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735295/minimal-example-opening-a-window-in-electron-from-react-application ?